# Cleaning data in an array method, not printing what it's supposed to?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, code.org

**Instructions**

***In SalesAnalyzer.java:***
Write the cleanData() method.
Traverse the sales array and use Math.abs() to get the absolute value of each value in the array.
Return a new array that contains the corrected sales values.

***In MyConsole.java:***
Declare and initialize a new array called correctedSales that stores the array returned from the cleanData() method.
Print the values stored in the correctedSales array.

```
                               **The Code...**
```

**My Console.Java**

```
public class MyConsole {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[] sales = {-4.05, 5.06, 3.99, -3.99, -1.99, 2.05, 10.50, -7.85, 6.73, -8.45};
    SalesAnalyzer mySales = new SalesAnalyzer(sales);

    // TO DO #2: Call the cleanData() method.
double [] correctedSale = mySales.cleanData();
  System.out.println("\n\n \n");
//System.out.println(correctedSale);
    for(double c: correctedSale){  // that list top 30 low pop from getLowPopCountrie
     System.out.println(c);// supposed to cycle through array and print out new elements
      }
    // TO DO #3: Print the values stored in the new array
  }
}
```

**Sales Analyzer**

```
 Analyzes sales data for a business
 */
public class SalesAnalyzer {

  private double[] sales;  // The list of sales

  /*
   * Constructor to create a SalesAnalyzer
   * with the specified array of sales
   */
  public SalesAnalyzer(double[] sales) {
    this.sales = sales;
  }

  /*
   * Returns a new array containing corrected sales values
   */
  public double[] cleanData() {
    double[] cleanList= new double[sales.length];
    // TO DO #1: Return a new array containing the corrected sales values.
 //for(double values : sales){
   // double result = Math.abs(values);
   //}
 int track = 0; // tracking 
 for(int index = 0; index< sales.length; index ++){ // cyling through array, starting @ first index
  // if(sales[index] < 15){ // current element less than 15
     if (track < sales.length){ // making sure both lists are the same length
       sales[track] = cleanList[index]; //aligning w new lisy
       cleanList[index] = Math.abs(index);
       track ++; // track out of 30
     } //brack 4 if 2
  // }// brack for if []
    //return cleanList;
  }
    return cleanList;
 }  
  
}
```

**Original Array**:{-4.05, 5.06, 3.99, -3.99, -1.99, 2.05, 10.50, -7.85, 6.73, -8.45};
**Whats Printed**:{0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0}
**Has to be**{4.05, 5.06, 3.99, 3.99, 1.99, 2.05, 10.50, 7.85, 6.73, 8.45};

Comment: You need to add the [tag:Java] tag and possibly remove the [tag:Math] tag as the question is not really about math.

Comment: You seem to be making it more complicated than it needs to be. Simply call `Math.abs()` on every element in `sales`, i.e. `for (int i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {cleanList[i] = Math.abs(sales[i]);}`